# why are the sub menus displayed correctly in firefox but not chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress

why does chrome display an extra 10 pixels, on the child menus? do they render the position differently, in regards to the parent menu? here is the css:

```
#nav ul li ul{
display: none;
width: 250px;
opacity: .7;
z-index: 999;

}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
background-color: #444444;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
border-top: 19px solid black;
}
```

see it in action:

http://guardianweb.edulence.com/model3/

Comment: Chrome displays everything exactly like you have it specified in your css. But Firefox don't takes the top:20px; for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [what I can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbg7e.jpg), it looks like Chrome and IE9 are rendering the page appropriately, but Firefox 11 is not. Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9FOD.png) the extra 10 pixels you are referring to?

Personally, I'd drop the `top: 20px` to have Firefox 11 render the sub-menus the same as Chrome and IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 19px border on top of your `li:hover ul` which is not measured into the height of the box adding, essentially, another 19px gap above your subnav. Also around line 80 of your styles.css you'll see that `#nav ul` gets `padding:10px 0;` it's being applied to the subnav too. giving it 10px padding above the first `li`